# Xubuntu 13.04 cant download magnets

Tags: transmission, xubuntu

Upgraded to Xubuntu 13.04 and cant open click on magnet links any more. Tried kTorrent instead of transmission. Same thing.

```
Unable to detect the URI-scheme of
"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:2418c7c1ad55d86b68ff807b3aac723c500d3f08&dn=Europa+Report+2013+WEBRip+XviD-PTpOWeR&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337".
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the new software of the torrent tracker. For example; I installed the latest qbittorrent and the same thing happened. I then downgraded to an older qbittorrent, and it works fine now. Good luck.

Comment: Why the *tracker*?